# Translate text in .val()

Tags: wordpress, translation, qtranslate

I have this line code:

```
$('#ss_account_submit').val('Create Account!');
```

So the .val() has a text within it. I wonder dow do I get to translate with qTranslate (WordPress plugin) a text within .js code like the line above:

The qTranslate allow to use quick shortcodes or regular shortcodes such as:

```
[:pt] For Brazilian Portuguese Language
[:en] For English Language
<!--:pt--><!--:--> For Brazilian Portuguese Language
<!--:en--><!--:--> For English Language
```

I tried a lot of things with my low knowledge in PHP/JS that didn't work, such as:

```
$('#ss_account_submit').val('[:pt]Crie uma conta![:en]Create Account!');

$('#ss_account_submit').val('<--:pt-->Crie uma conta!<--:--><--:en-->Create Account!<--:pt-->');

$('#ss_account_submit').val __(('<--:pt-->Crie uma conta!<--:--><--:en-->Create Account!<--:pt-->'));

$('#ss_account_submit').val (<?php __('<--:pt-->Crie uma conta!<--:--><--:en-->Create Account!<--:pt-->') ?>);
```

Another way to make translation works is by using this kind of codes:

```
<?php echo __('<--:pt-->Crie uma conta!<--:--><--:en-->Create Account!<--:pt-->') ?>
```

OR

```
(__('[:pt]Crie uma conta![:en]Create Account!'))
```

Any idea what could work for this original line?

```
$('#ss_account_submit').val('Create Account!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting looks a little off. Have you tried:

```
<?php _e("<!--:pt-->Crie uma conta<!--:--><!--:en-->Create Account<!--:-->"); ?>
```

Note: that will not work inside a standard .js file.

Comment: ^Hi, but how do I use your code into it:

    $('#ss_account_submit').val('Create Account!');

it doesn't work if using this way:

    $('#ss_account_submit').val(<?php _e("<!--:pt-->Crie uma conta<!--:--><!--:en-->Create Account<!--:-->"); ?>);

Answer (score 0):

Though its very late. But I see none answered it the right way.

When you are using `_()` or `__()` or `gettext()` or `_e()` or `_x()` or `_ex()` or `_n()` or  `_nx()` methods you are supposed to enclose only a single language inside it. See the full guide of [i18n](https://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers)

What the below line means is:

```
$('#ss_account_submit').val('<?php __('Create Account!')?>');
```

It would add the val in the current language of the site when executed.

You'd have to run a PoEdit on your template and get these lines with `__()` into the `.po` and translate them.

Alternatively,

You'd have to write conditional php section to select the right language.

```php
        $lingo = qtrans_getLanguage();
        if ( 'en' == $lingo )
            echo "$('#ss_account_submit').val('Create Account!')";
        if ( 'pt' == $lingo )
            echo "$('#ss_account_submit').val('Crie uma conta!');";
```